# Postgresql: how sort records in groups with n step

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have in my table rows ordered by **rank**. All **rank** values are different. Also I have **color** column with possible values (red, blue, green). I need iterate over earch row (named it *X* for example) and check if in next **n** rows exist row (named it *Y* for example) where *X.color == Y.color* then need move *Y* row and insert it after *X* row. 
For example **n = 5** and starting table:

```
id  rank    color
1   0.8     red                                               
3   0.76    blue                                              
4   0.75    blue                                              
7   0.743   green                                             
5   0.742   red                                               
6   0.741   green                                             
8   0.6     blue                                              
9   0.5     blue                                              
11  0.47    green                                             
12  0.45    blue                                              
10  0.4     red
```

1 Iterate, we have row with color **red** in next **n** rows, then:

```
  id    rank    color
    1   0.8     red
    5   0.742   red                                                                                              
    3   0.76    blue                                              
    4   0.75    blue                                              
    7   0.743   green                                             
    6   0.741   green                                             
    8   0.6     blue                                              
    9   0.5     blue                                              
    11  0.47    green                                             
    12  0.45    blue                                              
    10  0.4     red
```

2 Iterate, we don't have **red** in next **n** rows, then no changes

3 Iterate, we have **blue** in next **n** rows, but next blue row already after current.

4 Iterate, we have **blue** in next **n** rows, then:

```
  id    rank    color
    1   0.8     red
    5   0.742   red                                                                                              
    3   0.76    blue                                              
    4   0.75    blue
    8   0.6     blue                                                                                            
    7   0.743   green                                             
    6   0.741   green                                             
    9   0.5     blue                                              
    11  0.47    green                                             
    12  0.45    blue                                              
    10  0.4     red
```

5 Iterate, we have **blue** in next **n** rows, then:

```
  id    rank    color
    1   0.8     red
    5   0.742   red                                                                                              
    3   0.76    blue                                              
    4   0.75    blue
    8   0.6     blue
    9   0.5     blue                                                                                                                                          
    7   0.743   green                                             
    6   0.741   green                                             
    11  0.47    green                                             
    12  0.45    blue                                              
    10  0.4     red
```

6 Iterate, we have **blue** in next **n** rows, then:

```
  id    rank    color
    1   0.8     red
    5   0.742   red                                                                                              
    3   0.76    blue                                              
    4   0.75    blue
    8   0.6     blue
    9   0.5     blue
    12  0.45    blue                                                                                                                                                                                        
    7   0.743   green                                             
    6   0.741   green                                             
    11  0.47    green                                             
    10  0.4     red
```

7 Iterate, we have **green** in next **n** rows, but next green row already after current.

8 Iterate, we have **green** in next **n** rows, but next green row already after current.

9 Iterate, we have **green** in next **n** rows, but next green row already after current.

10 Iterate no changes.

Someone has an idea how to solve this problem, I tried to fasten window functions, but it is not clear whether it can be done with the help of them, maybe some other mechanism is needed?

Comment: You speak of the "next n rows". Is the ordering that is implied the ordering by `rank`? What do you mean when you speak about "moving a row": changing its `rank` or physically moving it in the (heap) table?

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe 1) Originally records sorted by rank, after the iterations, they are not fully sorted by rank - as in the example 2) "moving a row" means reordering rows in current request

Comment: You surely need to write a function for that because after every iteration you have a complete different data set you are working for. A simple query cannot work on different data sets within one call. An alternative could be trying an approach using a recursive CTE but I am not sure if this would work. A function might be faster

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's really common for folks relatively new to SQL to think about iteration when faced with a problem like this, but it is possible to do this without any iteration.  Let's break it down a bit.  First, let's find the row_id of all the data, based on the rank column:

```
with data as (select * from (values
(1,0.8 ,'red'),
(3,0.76 ,'blue'),
(4,0.75 ,'blue'),
(7,0.743 ,'green'),
(5,0.742 ,'red'),
(6,0.741 ,'green'),
(8,0.6 ,'blue'),
(9,0.5 ,'blue'),
(11,0.47 ,'green'),
(12,0.45 ,'blue'),
(10,0.4 ,'red')
) v(id, rank, color)
)
select id, rank, color,
  row_number() over (order by rank desc) as row_id
FROM data
ORDER BY rank desc;
 id | rank  | color | row_id
----+-------+-------+--------
  1 |   0.8 | red   |      1
  3 |  0.76 | blue  |      2
  4 |  0.75 | blue  |      3
  7 | 0.743 | green |      4
  5 | 0.742 | red   |      5
  6 | 0.741 | green |      6
  8 |   0.6 | blue  |      7
  9 |   0.5 | blue  |      8
 11 |  0.47 | green |      9
 12 |  0.45 | blue  |     10
 10 |   0.4 | red   |     11
(11 rows)
```

From there, we can figure out the minimum row in the previous five rows that has the same color:

```
with data as (select * from (values
(1,0.8 ,'red'),
(3,0.76 ,'blue'),
(4,0.75 ,'blue'),
(7,0.743 ,'green'),
(5,0.742 ,'red'),
(6,0.741 ,'green'),
(8,0.6 ,'blue'),
(9,0.5 ,'blue'),
(11,0.47 ,'green'),
(12,0.45 ,'blue'),
(10,0.4 ,'red')
) v(id, rank, color)
), all_rows as (
select id, rank, color,
  row_number() over (order by rank desc) as row_id
FROM data
ORDER BY rank desc
)
select id, rank, color, row_id,
  first_value(row_id) over (partition by color order by row_id range between 5 
  preceding and current row)
from all_rows
order by 5, rank desc;
 id | rank  | color | row_id | first_value
----+-------+-------+--------+-------------
  1 |   0.8 | red   |      1 |           1
  5 | 0.742 | red   |      5 |           1
  3 |  0.76 | blue  |      2 |           2
  4 |  0.75 | blue  |      3 |           2
  8 |   0.6 | blue  |      7 |           2
  9 |   0.5 | blue  |      8 |           3
  7 | 0.743 | green |      4 |           4
  6 | 0.741 | green |      6 |           4
 11 |  0.47 | green |      9 |           4
 12 |  0.45 | blue  |     10 |           7
 10 |   0.4 | red   |     11 |          11
(11 rows)
```

This is close, but it's not quite right.  We need to get the minimum of that minimum from the last 5 rows for each color.  We'll need one more step:

```
with data as (select * from (values
(1,0.8 ,'red'),
(3,0.76 ,'blue'),
(4,0.75 ,'blue'),
(7,0.743 ,'green'),
(5,0.742 ,'red'),
(6,0.741 ,'green'),
(8,0.6 ,'blue'),
(9,0.5 ,'blue'),
(11,0.47 ,'green'),
(12,0.45 ,'blue'),
(10,0.4 ,'red')
) v(id, rank, color)
), all_rows as (
select id, rank, color,
  row_number() over (order by rank desc) as row_id
FROM data
ORDER BY rank desc
), first_values as (
select id, rank, color, row_id,
  first_value(row_id) over (partition by color order by row_id range between 5 
  preceding and current row)
from all_rows
order by 5, rank desc
)
select id, rank, color, row_id,
first_value(first_value) over (partition by color order by row_id range between 5 preceding and current row) as overall_rank
FROM first_values
ORDER BY overall_rank, rank desc
;
 id | rank  | color | row_id | overall_rank
----+-------+-------+--------+--------------
  1 |   0.8 | red   |      1 |            1
  5 | 0.742 | red   |      5 |            1
  3 |  0.76 | blue  |      2 |            2
  4 |  0.75 | blue  |      3 |            2
  8 |   0.6 | blue  |      7 |            2
  9 |   0.5 | blue  |      8 |            2
 12 |  0.45 | blue  |     10 |            2
  7 | 0.743 | green |      4 |            4
  6 | 0.741 | green |      6 |            4
 11 |  0.47 | green |      9 |            4
 10 |   0.4 | red   |     11 |           11
(11 rows)
```